# Issues with database when importing huge amount of data to Odoo

Tags: postgresql, odoo, psql, odoo-12, openerp-7

I'm facing a quite confusing issue here. I want to import a very large amount of data, a total of 73076, from an external API using a simple HTTP controller. However, when I create the data through the `request.env[MODEL].sudo().create()`, it always only can be created for around 18538 of the data and leaves the rest uncreated.

I inspect and debug it carefully and find out that, actually, the whole data has already been successfully retrieved, and the main issue is that Odoo always reaches the server limitations with this message always shown in the logger:

`Thread <Thread(odoo.service.http.request ...... virtual real time limit ....`

I've tried modifying my server configuration and setting and adjusting the limit_memory_hard, limit_memory_soft, limit_time_real, and limit_time_cpu to my specifications. I even modified the Postgre configuration in `/etc/postgresql/14/main/postgresql.conf` by adding the mem_size and shared buffers, but nothing was solved.

I even separating the the route into two related route, the first one is only creating 15000 amount of data, and the second one is create the rest, but still unsolved.

What actually happened here? Is there any way to address this issue, or has anyone here faced the same issue while importing a huge amount of data in the past?

EDIT: Below is the full code of the controllers

```py
    @http.route('/get_json_responses_daily_stock', auth='public', method=['GET'])
    def get_json_responses_daily_stock(self, **kw):
        max_attempts = 3  # Maximum number of retry attempts
        attempt_delay = 5  # Delay between retry attempts in seconds

        for attempt in range(1, max_attempts + 1):
            try:
                daily_stock_id = self._get_daily_stock_id()
                if not daily_stock_id:
                    return self.create_json_response("error", "No Daily Stock records are found.")
                else:
                    kode_cabang = daily_stock_id.s_kode_cabang.lower()

                url1 = f"http://192.168.16.130/portal/bis_{kode_cabang}/bisreport/getDailyStock"
                # response1 = requests.get(url1)
                response1 = requests.post(url1, data={})
                response1.raise_for_status()

                # Check response from external endpoint
                if response1.status_code != 200:
                    return json.dumps({"error": "External endpoint didn't responds with status 200"})

                # Get from internal
                # url2 = "http://192.168.16.130/microservice_internal/bis-pivot/bis/getDailyStock"
                url2 = f"http://192.168.16.130/microservice_internal/bis-pivot/bis/getDailyStock/?kode_cabang={kode_cabang.upper()}"
                response2 = requests.get(url2)
                response2.raise_for_status()
                jakarta_tz = timezone('Asia/Jakarta')
                current_time = datetime.now(jakarta_tz)
                current_date_str = current_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                request.env.cr.execute(f"DELETE FROM daily_stock WHERE fetch_date > '{current_date_str}'::date - INTERVAL '1 day'")
                request.env.cr.commit()

                daily_stock_model = request.env['daily.stock'].sudo()
                data = response2.json()
                res_data = data.get('data')
                total_records = len(res_data)
                print("------------------ LENGTH OF RESDAT ------------------")
                print(total_records)

                # Process data in chunks
                chunk_size = 15000
                records_created = 0

                for i in range(0, len(res_data), chunk_size):
                    chunk = res_data[i:i + chunk_size]

                    # Process each item in the chunk
                    for item in chunk:
                        fetch_date = item.get('fetch_date')
                        if fetch_date in ['0000-00-00', '']:
                            fetch_date = None
                        existing_daily_stock = daily_stock_model.search([
                            ('kode_barang', '=', item.get('kode_barang'))
                        ], limit=1)
                        if not existing_daily_stock:
                            daily_stock_model.create({
                                'kode_cabang': item.get('kode_cabang'),
                                'nama_cabang': item.get('nama_cabang'),
                                'kode_barang': item.get('kode_barang'),
                                'kode_barang_principal': item.get('kode_barang_principal'),
                                'group_barang': item.get('group_barang'),
                                'category_barang': item.get('category_barang'),
                                'nama_barang': item.get('nama_barang'),
                                'kode_principal': item.get('kode_principal'),
                                'Kode_Divisi_Produk': item.get('Kode_Divisi_Produk'),
                                'jenis_barang': item.get('jenis_barang'),
                                'harga_terkini': item.get('harga_terkini'),
                                'harga_terkecil': item.get('harga_terkecil'),
                                'harga_terbesar': item.get('harga_terbesar'),
                                'qty_satuan': item.get('qty_satuan'),
                                'satuan_terbesar': item.get('satuan_terbesar'),
                                'qty_satuan_kecil': item.get('qty_satuan_kecil'),
                                'satuan_terkecil': item.get('satuan_terkecil'),
                                'qty_awal': item.get('qty_awal'),
                                'qty_akhir': item.get('qty_akhir'),
                                'tanggal_penarikan_awal': item.get('tanggal_penarikan_awal') if item.get('tanggal_penarikan_awal') not in ['0000-00-00', ''] else None,
                                'tanggal_penarikan_akhir': item.get('tanggal_penarikan_akhir') if item.get('tanggal_penarikan_akhir') not in ['0000-00-00', ''] else None,
                                'fetch_date': item.get('fetch_date') if item.get('fetch_date') not in ['0000-00-00', ''] else None,
                            })
                            records_created += 1
                            print(f"Record created: {records_created}/{total_records}")

                    # Commit changes after processing each chunk
                    daily_stock_model.env.cr.commit()

                    # Check if we need to switch to the extended route
                    if records_created >= chunk_size:
                        action = request.env['ir.actions.act_window'].sudo().search([('name', '=', 'Daily Stock')], limit=1)
                        action_id = action.id if action else None

                        menu = request.env['ir.ui.menu'].sudo().search([('name', '=', 'Daily Stock')], limit=1)
                        menu_id = menu.id if menu else None

                        remaining_data = res_data[records_created:]
                        request.session['remaining_data'] = remaining_data
                        request.session['action_id'] = action_id
                        request.session['menu_id'] = menu_id
                        request.session['attempt'] = attempt
                        request.session['max_attempts'] = max_attempts
                        request.session['records_created'] = records_created
                        request.session['total_records'] = total_records

                        return request.redirect('/get_json_responses_daily_stock_extended')
                
                # data_to_unlink = request.env['daily.stock'].sudo().search([('is_input', '=', True)])
                # data_to_unlink.unlink()

                # action = request.env['ir.actions.act_window'].sudo().search([('name', '=', 'Daily Stock')], limit=1)
                # action_id = action.id if action else None

                # menu = request.env['ir.ui.menu'].sudo().search([('name', '=', 'Daily Stock')], limit=1)
                # menu_id = menu.id if menu else None

                return request.redirect(f'/web#action={action_id}&menu_id={menu_id}')

            except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
                if attempt < max_attempts:
                    print(f"Attempt {attempt} failed. Retrying in {attempt_delay} seconds.")
                    time.sleep(attempt_delay)
                else:
                    return json.dumps({'error': str(e)})


    @http.route('/get_json_responses_daily_stock_extended', auth='public', method=['GET'])
    def get_json_responses_daily_stock_extended(self, **kw):
        try:
            # Retrieve the data from sessions
            remaining_data = request.session.get('remaining_data', [])
            action_id = request.session.get('action_id')
            menu_id = request.session.get('menu_id')
            attempt = request.session.get('attempt')
            max_attempts = request.session.get('max_attempts')
            records_created = request.session.get('records_created')
            total_records = request.session.get('total_records')

            daily_stock_model = request.env['daily.stock'].sudo()

            for item in remaining_data:
                fetch_date = item.get('fetch_date')
                if fetch_date in ['0000-00-00', '']:
                    fetch_date = None
                existing_daily_stock = daily_stock_model.search([
                    ('kode_barang', '=', item.get('kode_barang'))
                ], limit=1)
                if not existing_daily_stock:
                    daily_stock_model.create({
                        'kode_cabang': item.get('kode_cabang'),
                        'nama_cabang': item.get('nama_cabang'),
                        'kode_barang': item.get('kode_barang'),
                        'kode_barang_principal': item.get('kode_barang_principal'),
                        'group_barang': item.get('group_barang'),
                        'category_barang': item.get('category_barang'),
                        'nama_barang': item.get('nama_barang'),
                        'kode_principal': item.get('kode_principal'),
                        'Kode_Divisi_Produk': item.get('Kode_Divisi_Produk'),
                        'jenis_barang': item.get('jenis_barang'),
                        'harga_terkini': item.get('harga_terkini'),
                        'harga_terkecil': item.get('harga_terkecil'),
                        'harga_terbesar': item.get('harga_terbesar'),
                        'qty_satuan': item.get('qty_satuan'),
                        'satuan_terbesar': item.get('satuan_terbesar'),
                        'qty_satuan_kecil': item.get('qty_satuan_kecil'),
                        'satuan_terkecil': item.get('satuan_terkecil'),
                        'qty_awal': item.get('qty_awal'),
                        'qty_akhir': item.get('qty_akhir'),
                        'tanggal_penarikan_awal': item.get('tanggal_penarikan_awal') if item.get('tanggal_penarikan_awal') not in ['0000-00-00', ''] else None,
                        'tanggal_penarikan_akhir': item.get('tanggal_penarikan_akhir') if item.get('tanggal_penarikan_akhir') not in ['0000-00-00', ''] else None,
                        'fetch_date': item.get('fetch_date') if item.get('fetch_date') not in ['0000-00-00', ''] else None,
                    })
                    records_created += 1
                    print(f"Record created: {records_created}/{total_records}")

                    # Commit changes after processing the remaining data
                    daily_stock_model.env.cr.commit()

            unlink_res = helpers.unlink_the_sp_input_data()
            if unlink_res:
                return request.redirect(f"/web#action={action_id}&menu_id={menu_id}")
            else:
                error_borrrr

        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            if attempt < max_attempts:
                print(f"Attempt {attempt} failed. Retrying in {attempt_delay} seconds.")
                time.sleep(attempt_delay)
            else:
                return json.dumps({'error': str(e)})
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you checked your logs on the webserver side of things? Or timeouts etc? If PostgreSQL is throwing errors it logs them, so if you haven't found errors in its logs look elsewhere for the problem.

Comment: Take a look at [Real time limit reached](https://mellowhost.com/blog/odoo-error-virtual-real-time-limit-151-120s-reached.html) and see if that is what you did.

Comment: @RichardHuxton yes, but the logs didn't show any error (written in red) logs, just that thread limit

Comment: @AdrianKlaver done that already, but nothing solved.